# Default port for SQL-Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

In my local system I used sql express and I know the default port is 1433.
Now I started work on remote sql server (microsoft SQL azure), I don't know how to connect my application(mathematica) with remote database. I have following details

```
UserName: xxxxxxx
ServerName: xxxx7iuiuh6.database.windows.net
Password: xxxxxxx
```

I can connect to this database from SSMS but not from my application(mathematica), It ask me for hostname, port number, Username and password. I have username and password but not hostname and port. So I can't connect to remote database from my application.

Is there any default port number for remote database, I tried with server name instead of hostname and default port number 1433 but no luck.

can any one help me?

Answer (score 5):

You hostname should be the server name (xxxx7iuiuh6.database.windows.net), and the port is also 1433 in SQL Azure (now called SQL Database). You may also want to force the TCP protocol which is the only one supported; try the hostname as tcp:xxxx7iuiuh6.database.windows.net

Note that in some applications, the username should be , so in your case your user name can be either "yourusername" or "yourusername@xxxx7iuiuh6".

Comment: I have tried with 1433 and xxxx7iuiuh6.database.windows.net but it's not working.